# How to select item in one table that is not present in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

The following table is REORGANISED table

```
TID ITEMS      TIMES  TWU  
1   D           5   633
1   M           5   665
1   R           14  861
1   F           4   871
1   I           8   910
1   A           7   942
1   N           7   950
1   Z           2   986
1   H           2   1020
2   S           4   551
2   R           7   861
2   F           6   871
2   I           4   910
2   A           6   942
2   N           8   950
2   Z           6   986
2   H           2   1020
3   U           4   354
3   V           7   528
3   B           2   641
3   J           4   842
3   F           4   871
3   I           2   910
3   A           6   942
3   N           2   950
3   Z           4   986
4   X           4   338
4   O           2   442
4   D           2   633
4   B           6   641
4   M           1   665
4   F           5   871
4   A           1   942
4   N           7   950
4   Z           10  986
4   H           1   1020
5   T           5   365
5   C           8   370
5   K           7   397
5   Q           5   397
5   P           5   471
5   S           3   551
5   D           1   633
5   B           6   641
5   M           6   665
5   J           4   842
5   R           6   861
5   I           1   910
5   A           4   942
5   Z           10  986
5   H           7   1020    
6   L           5   305
6   U           1   354
6   K           2   397
```

Above table is sorted in ascending order..I considered the minimum value of twu's item as leaf node for each TID..remaining items are intermediate node..The following table is LEAFNODES

```
TID  ITEMS  
1   D         
2   S         
3   U         
4   X         
5   T         
6   L
```

Now i want to select ITEMS in LEAFNODES that is not present as intermediate node in reorganised

Comment: Please dont dump whole table here. Learn to format your post!

Comment: I suspect you are looking for tid-items pairs from leafnodes not present in reorganised, yes? So you expect no result rows, as all pairs in leafnodes are present in reorganised, yes?

Comment: @thorsten..I selected items in leafnode from reorganised table so item in leafnode table must present in first column of each tid in reorganised table..i want to select item in leafnodes table that is not present in intermediate cell instead of 1st column in reorganised table sir...

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. What is an "intermediate cell"? Better show your expected results and tell us why you expect these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get records that do not exist in another table, you use NOT EXISTS. You want to know whether intermediate records exist. You consider all records that don't have the minimun twu per tid an intermediate record. So all records with a higher twu than minimum are intermediate, and you want to select all items from leafnodes that are not intermediate.

```
select *
from leafnodes
where not exists
(
  select *
  from reorganized
  where twu > 
  (
    select min(twu)
    from reorganized leaf
    where leaf.tid = reorganized.tid
  )
  and reorganized.items = leafnodes.items
);
```

Here is the same with an IN clause, which I consider slightly more readable. Here you regard the intermediate items a set, and you want an item NOT to be IN that set.

```
select *
from leafnodes
where items not in
(
  select items
  from reorganized
  where twu > 
  (
    select min(twu)
    from reorganized leaf
    where leaf.tid = reorganized.tid
  )
);
```

Comment: @thorsten...sir In leafnode table i used min() function to select item from reorganised...so items in leafnode table must present in reorganised table in first column for each TID

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @thorsten...sorry sir...consider my reorganised table as a tree..each tid is a seperate branch..in each tid the item which have lowest TWU is leaf node remaining are a intermediate node..now i want to select leaf node for any tid which is not present as intermediate node in any other tid

Comment: Okay, I've changed my answer accordingly. As mentioned, you could have made your request much clearer by showing the result records you want to see.

Comment: Thank u soo much sir :) itz working...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from LEAFNODES

Excluse

(with temp as 
(select TID ,  min(TWU) as TWU from LEAFNODES )

select TID , Items from REORGANISED as a inner join temp  on a.TID=temp.TID and a.TWU=Temp.TWU))
```

Comment: It is usually helpful to provide some explanation as to what your code is doing rather than just the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    -- Select the TId with minimum value from  REORGANISED
    SELECT TID,MIN(TWU)TWU 
    FROM REORGANISED
    GROUP BY TID
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Now we will get value(ITEMS) for the min value and TID from CTE1 for 
    SELECT C1.TID,R.ITEMS,C1.TWU 
    FROM CTE1 C1 
    JOIN REORGANISED R ON C1.TID=R.TID AND C1.TWU=R.TWU
)
SELECT L.* 
FROM CTE2 C2
JOIN LEAFNODES L ON C2.TID=L.TID AND C2.ITEMS=L.ITEMS
```